# How to get link of a particular anchor whose text is known

Tags: javascript

I am parsing a HTML file reqularly. There is a link with a constant text as follows:

```
<a href="www.abc.com">Static Text</a>
```

Is there any way to get href as follows?

```
xyz.findTagByTextContent('Static Text').getAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own util for that:

```
function getLinksByText(text) {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter(({ innerText }) => innerText === text);
}
```

It will return an array of links with passed text.
And after that you can use it like

```
getLinksByText('Static Text')[0].getAttribute('href')
```

If you need to get only first entry instead of array of all entries - just use `.find` instead of `.filter`

Comment: Any php alternative?

Comment: @Mehmed what do you mean? Are you asking question about JS or PHP?

Comment: both, but php tag is removed.